# Flattening a sealed bag in space

Tags: pressure, vacuum, air, volume

Let's say you're in space, and you have an empty, sealed, round bag in space (full of "nothing" since there's no air).

Is it possible to flatten the bag without unsealing it?

My understanding is that the internal volume of a sealed bag on Earth cannot be changed because the amount of air in the bag is constant. Isn't there's no such constraint if the bag contains nothing?

Edit: the bag isn't a perfect sphere, the question isn't about whether the bag can be made *perfectly* flat, but whether it's possible to make it approximately flat.

Comment: Do you mean making it approximately flat, then mmesser314 has given you the answer, there would be nothing to resist the flattening, or are you asking something more complicated about whether a sphere can be made into a completely flat circle?

Comment: I mean making it approximately flat

Comment: Then you should choose mmesser314's answer, there is no force opposing the flattening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. You could flatten it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to flatten the bag without unsealing it?

Whether it's sealed or unsealed really makes no difference if there is nothing inside or outside.

So it depends on the surface areas of the bag before and after flattening.

For a  spherical bag the surface area of the top half is $2\pi r^2$ and the distance between $A$ and $B$ is $\pi r$

[image]

After flattening, if the surface areas are equal (no stretching), $\pi r_f^2 = 2\pi r^2$, so $r_f = \sqrt{2} r$

But then distance $AB$ is $2\sqrt{2} r$, inconsistent with the previous distance.

So it seems as though there must be some crumpling and the bag couldn't be completely flat.

Comment: This is also called conservation of Gaussian curvature https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature#Important_theorems